# Workflow - local and remote

Tags: git

Am trying to upgrade my workflow: I mainly go from psd-html-ftp.

I've been looking into a  git>local(mamp)/stage>deployment style workflow and am having some blocks.

1. Git - I am finally using git (git hub) still trying to get the hang of it, but it seems pretty useful so far.
2. Development Server - I have MAMP and have used it, but typically once a site is live, I  work off of the live site. Most everything I do is cms driven, either wordpress or symphony cms. I am not sure how I would clone a database? In other words, I am not sure how to set up a staging/development area for live sites that are in sync.
3. I like the idea of bypassing ftp and cloning to the server either with beanstalk or git ssh (if I am correct.) However, I work on say 10-20 sites and find it hard to pay $20+ a month for a few private repositories. Unless I am misunderstanding, there is no need to push to a private repository (for me) as I already backup with dropbox, but the clone to server is a nice solution.

I hope you won't chew me out for this overall question and am not asking for product advice necessarily, just trying to improve my workflow and want to confirm and get help on certain parts of it.

Comment: This article may help you a bit: http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

Comment: For the github part ($20+ concern) you can use [Bitbucket| http://bitbucket.org]. It has unlimited private repositories for free - but limits the number of developers working simultaneously. I can guess you probably don't have many co-workers and bitbucket would be best in such case.

Comment: this would be it! Mainly it's just me.